# How to patch a file that is not in a module's git repo?

Tags: commerce

I want to patch `CheckoutCartEventSubscriber.php`, which can be found in `/web/modules/contrib/commerce/modules/checkout/src/EventSubscriber` when installed via composer.

So I cloned Commerce from the drupal.org git repository, navigated to the `/modules/checkout/src/`, and found that there is no **EventSubscriber** directory.  All the other directories that can be found in the composer install exist except **EventSubscriber**.

[The github repo browser doesn't show the EventSubscriber directory, either.](https://github.com/drupalcommerce/commerce/tree/8.x-2.x/modules/checkout/src)

So where is this directory? How can I find the file to patch it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That gihub repository looks to be outdated, as the last commit was made May 15, 2020

To see a module's repository, go to the projects page and click on on "[Browse code repository](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/commerce)"

[image]

Which will take you to the GitLab repository.

---

> So where is this directory?

Well... that directory doesn't exist. Maybe your composer.json already contains a patch that creates it? OR someone manually added that folder and file, as that folder and file is not officially part of Commerce.

Comment: A patch was at fault.  Thanks, it totally slipped my mind that a patch could cause an issue like this.